# Activator.CreateInstance Exception

Tags: c#, exception, activator

```
DBHandler.IDB dbHandler;

fileManager fileManager = fileManager.getFileManager();
String dbNameSpace = fileManager.getDBNameSpace();
String dbClassName = fileManager.getDBClassName();

System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + dbNameSpace + ".dll");
Debug.WriteLine("BEFORE ___________________________________________________");
ObjectHandle handle = Activator.CreateInstance(dbNameSpace, dbNameSpace + "." + dbClassName);
dbHandler = (DBHandler.IDB)handle.Unwrap();
```

In the code above I'm getting a file name from XML configuration file and trying to dynamically load the correct .dll (this part work fine) and after it instantiate the class to the object `dbHandler`.

After the `Create` instance method is being called I'm getting an exception:

> BEFORE **_______________________________________________**
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in     mscorlib.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException' occurred in System.Xaml.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException' occurred in System.Xaml.dll

I read somewhere that this may indicate a problem with the constructor that is being called, but I didn't implemented the constructor (using the default one).

Comment: *Never* use LoadFile(), it loads the assembly without a loading context so dependent assemblies cannot be found.  Use LoadFrom().  Using CurrentDirectory() is pretty fundamentally wrong as well, it is much too unpredictable.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you very much for the quick answer, i will see if that solves the problem.

So how can i get the solution current directory?

Comment: The text in the Output window that you've given isn't very helpful.  Add a try-catch block around the failing line and post the Exception message and any inner exception messages.

Comment: It looks like the change from LoadFile to LoadFrom solved my problem, thank you very much!
P.s
what is the correct way of getting my solution dir?

Comment: @Yogevnn You can find the path of running assembly via `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`
Also can you dbNameSpace and dbClassName in Debug window?

Comment: RezaRahmati Thank you!

@martin_costello i was wrong the problem is still occurring. this is the exception being thrown: 

'devenv.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Yogev\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\YNIDS\YNIDS\bin\Debug\sqlServerDB.dll'
BEFORE ___________________________________________________
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'sqlServerDB' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'sqlServerDB'

Comment: So is this file in your "bin\Debug" folder (or wherever the code gets compiled to) that the application runs in when you're debugging?

Comment: Yes, i can see the dll in the bin\Debug folder

There is also this message above the exception:
    Loaded 'C:\Users\Yogev\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\YNIDS\YNIDS\bin\Debug\sqlServerDB.dll'

Comment: Ok so i have isolated the exception and now it say this:
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
And then when i try to instantiate the object it decided that one of my methods has no implementation, although  it has.
@martin_costello